# Cannot Stub method "title" because no such method exist in the mocked class OCMock

Tags: ios, objective-c, ocmock

I'm writing this unit test:

```
   - (void)testCellValues
{
    id bookMock = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[LBBook class]];
    [[[bookMock stub] andReturn:@"Book Title"] title];
}
```

Of course there is some code after that. But at this point I'm having this error when I execute the test:

```
[LBReviewsDashboardDataSourceTest testCellValues] failed: OCMockObject[LBBook]: cannot stub or expect method 'title' because no such method exists in the mocked class.
```

But `LBBook` class has the attribute `title`.  This is the LBBook Class:

```
@interface LBBook : LBManagedObjectFactory

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * title;

@end
```

I cannot realise what is happening here, why Does OCMock return that error if the class has title `attribute`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the inheritance hierarchy for `LBBook`? How is the `title` property implemented? Is there an `@synthesize` for the property in the implementation?

Comment: Yes it is @ErikDoernenburg and the hierarchy for LBBook is a NSManagedObject

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CoreData uses dynamic properties. These are not yet properly supported in OCMock. It is possible to stub `valueForKey:` instead. See also: [OCMock: stub a @dynamic property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17190130/ocmock-stub-a-dynamic-property) and [OCMock with Core Data dynamic properties problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876568/ocmock-with-core-data-dynamic-properties-problem)

Comment: Thanks thats the answer!